# Best way to handle unique together error - Django 2.2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I know this question has been asked many times, but still i am unable to find the right solution., let's say i have model like follow

```
class Student(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
       constraints = [
                     models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['department', 'number'])
                     ]
```

and my serializer look like follow.

```
class StudentModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Student
          fields = ("number",)
```

In this model `department` and `number` is `unique together`, now the department is fetched from `pk` passed in url. the way i am handling unique error is like follow.

```
class StudentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Student.objects.all()
     serializer_class = StudentModelSerializer

     def perform_create(self, serializer):
          department = Department.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
          serializer.save(department=department)

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
         except IntegrityError as err:
             if 'UNIQUE constraint' in err.message:
                raise ValidationError({
                    'number': 'Number field should be unique.'
                })
             else:
                raise IntegrityError(err)
```

As seen above i invoked the `super().create()` catch the exception, then checks the `UNIQUE` message presents, if present i am raising validation error again, so `rest framework's exception handler` handle that. if not i am raising error again.

The problem with this approach is i am checking unique error with the message `UNIQUE` which may change in future., of course i can add department to `serializer context` and `validate` before save, but that may lead to `race condition`, so what is `best practice` to handle scenario like this?

Comment: can you show the url config?

Comment: The end url should be like this `[POST]  http://localhost/departments/{pk}/students`

Comment: check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

A better way can be to compare the pgcode of exception to the psycopg2 error code :

```
from psycopg2 import errorcodes

class StudentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentModelSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        department = Department.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        serializer.save(department=department)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if err.__cause__.pgcode == errorcodes.UNIQUE_VIOLATION and \
               "number" in err.args[0]
                raise ValidationError({
                    'number': 'Number field should be unique.'
                })
            raise
```